# How to properly plan relative sizes of partitions?

Tags: linux, partition, size

At work our systems must have the following directories each on a dedicated partition:

```
/boot
/home
/audits
/opt
/tmp
/var
/home
/
```

There is no company policy or guidelines on the sizes they must be; that is left to the judgment of the sysadmin setting them up.

Currently, I have them set up as:

```
/dev/sda1    1GB    EXT3    /boot
/dev/sda2    8GB    SWAP    SWAP
/dev/sda3    265GB  EXT3    /home
/dev/sda4    191GB  EXTENDED
/dev/sda5    50GB   EXT3    /
/dev/sda6    50GB   EXT3    /audits
/dev/sda7    50GB   EXT3    /opt
/dev/sda8    20GB   EXT3    /tmp
/dev/sda9    20GB   EXT3    /var
```

This is just one specific server, of course, but are there any official guidelines (e.g. in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/)) specifying how much space should be allocated to each of these relative to the others?

If not, are there any objective reasons to prefer some particular pattern of relative allocation over a different one?

---

Below are the details of this particular server, as a case study:

System Components:
HP DL580G8: http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=6636692#!tab=specs

- (2) 500GB HDDs in a RAID 1 - `/dev/sda`
- (2) 300GB HDDs in a RAID 1 - `/dev/sdb` (unallocated)
- 32GB of RAM
- 4 - PROCs (16 cores)

I do not have any additional space nor can I get additional space. I can break up the RAID configurations if needed, but I do need to include some sort of redundancy.

OS: SLES 11 SP 4

Comment: What is `/audits`? Also, is there a reason you're using ext3 and not ext4?

Comment: Might be useful if you informed up what the workload is.  VMs?

Comment: How about `LVM` so you can resize them anytime on demand? Nobody can answer your question it depends on what you put in each of those locations...

Comment: - Company wants /var/log/audits segregated, so I created /audits on its own partition.

Comment: - I am using EXT3 because SLES 11 SP4 is not giving me the option for EXT4

Comment: - No VMs, just a server that is hosting proprietary simulation software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your goals are to:

- make as much space available for the users as possible
- not run out of disk space anywhere else and have to take the server down to resize them at a critical time

If that's true, I'd recommend swapping the drives in `sda` and `sdb` and using the now-500GB `sdb` purely for `/home`. Then you can divide up the 300GB `sda` however you like:

- I've had problems with 256MB `/boot` partitions running out of space when Ubuntu doesn't clean up old kernel releases, so I'd actually recommend going up to 5GB, but that's just my own once-bitten-twice-shy opinion. 1GB should be more than enough in most cases.
- Figure out the maximum you'll need for `/audits` and double that a few times.
- Would you ever need to hibernate? If so you'll need more swap space, but otherwise 8GB is probably enough. If you start regularly using swap space you need to figure out why and address that issue, anyway, so yes 8GB is probably plenty for you.
- Use something like LVM, if you can, for the majority of `sdb` so you can resize all those partitions without losing data *when* (not if) you need to.
- Once you've set aside enough for the rest of the partitions, put the rest in `/` which is where you're going to be installing most software anyway.
- Unless your main software goes into `/opt`, you can probably reduce `/opt`.
- If you know someone who is already using the software you're supporting, ask them if it uses `/tmp` a lot: that might let you know if you need to increase or can decrease that partition a little bit.

Comment: I applaud you, sir. Thanks! This is exactly the guidance I was looking for.